# Typescript Interface for Annoymous Function passed into React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-functional-component

I am learning to use Typescript with React functional components (a Bootstrap modal component) and became confused with how the Typescript interface should be properly defined for the component when an anonymous function is used.

In this example below, `TheModal` component is passed in a boolean `show` and a anonymous function `handleClose`.

```js
export function Foo(): JSX.Element {
    const [ showModal, setShowModal ] = useState(false);

    return (
        <MyContainer>
            <TheModal show={showModal} handleClose={ () => setShowModal(!showModal) } />
        </MyContainer>
    )
}
```

Below is the `TheModal` component and the Typescript interface definition `IModal`. Although the code runs, I think `any` should not be used for `handleClose`.

```js
interface IModal {
    show: boolean;
    handleClose: any;  // <======== I believe we should use something better than `any`
}

function TheModal({show, handleClose}: IModal): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Hello World</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

What is the correct way of defining the type for `handleClose` in `IModal`?

Comment: `Function` is any function and `() => void` is a function with no parameters that does not have to return a value, but by the look of your code the function is used as a Button onClick handler so you could type it the same as the onClick handler if you want to provide access to the synthetic event using something similar to: `(event: React.MouseEvent) => void;`

Comment: Instead of `(event: React.MouseEvent) => void;` it seems you can also define the function like this: `const handleClose: React.MouseEventHandler = () => {}`. Then in your interface you can use `handleClose: React.MouseEventHandler` too. Since this is built in I would assume it's intended rather than using `(event: React.MouseEvent) => void;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way fo typing handlers is to use React built in types:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IModal {
    show: boolean;
    handleClose: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}
```